# how to add update multiple response of a dialog node in IBM watson assistant with Nodejs

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I have a node application which is interacting with IBM watson assistant.
I need to update the response output of a dialog node and I'm using the following watson api

```
  var params = {
  workspace_id: //,
  dialog_node: 'greeting',
  new_dialog_node: 'greeting',
  new_output: {
    text: 'Hello! What can I do for you?'
    //add more than one text
  }
};

assistant.updateDialogNode(params, function(err, response) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } else {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
  }
  });
```

the API only accepts object type `text:'Hello! What can I do for you?'` this also overwrites the previous response

the error `[ { message: 'output should be of type Object', path: '.output' } ]`

How can I update the Dialog and add multiple responses at the same time or update the existing one?
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the following format for new_output?

`{
        "text": {
          "values": [
            "first response",
            "second response"
          ],
          "selection_policy": "sequential"
        }`